# Save the Hidden State of A UIButton

Tags: uibutton, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch that on Value Change, hides or unhides some UIButtons with an if statement.  I would like the hidden state of the UIButtons to be saved when I switch views or exit the app. I have tried using NSUserDefaults but it does not save, it just reverts back to the state I had originally set in the .storyboard

.m code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonHidden:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[Defaults setBool:china.hidden forKey:ChinaChanged];
[Defaults setBool:japan.hidden forKey:JapanChanged];
[Defaults setBool:french.hidden forKey:FrenchChanged];
[Defaults setBool:spanish.hidden forKey:SpanishChanged];
[Defaults synchronize];

}
```

.m viewDidLoad code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSUserDefaults *Defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
china.hidden = [Defaults boolForKey:ChinaChanged];
japan.hidden = [Defaults boolForKey:JapanChanged];
french.hidden = [Defaults boolForKey:FrenchChanged];
spanish.hidden = [Defaults boolForKey:SpanishChanged];

}
```

I do not know where I can connect the IBAction to make it work.

This is my if statement code for the UISwitch:

```
(IBAction)switchTheSwitch:(id)sender {
if (Languages.on) {
    china.hidden = NO;
    japan.hidden = NO;
    french.hidden = NO;
    spanish.hidden = NO;
}

else {
    china.hidden = YES;
    japan.hidden = YES;
    french.hidden = YES;
    spanish.hidden = YES;

    }
}
```

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure I follow but to me it seems all you lack is a call to `buttonHidden` so that defaults get actually saved

just do

```
-(IBAction)switchTheSwitch:(id)sender {
    if (Languages.on) {
        china.hidden = NO;
        japan.hidden = NO;
        french.hidden = NO;
        spanish.hidden = NO;
    }
    else {
        china.hidden = YES;
        japan.hidden = YES;
        french.hidden = YES;
        spanish.hidden = YES;
    }
    [self buttonHidden:sender];
}
```

Comment: Thank You So Much. I can't believe I just missed 1 line of Code.

Comment: is there a way i can put the switch on a different view and have it work

Comment: sure, the outlets can point to different views.. but I guess you mean ViewControllers!?